# Cannot resolve "Auth" in Firebase Chat Application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am learning how to implement Firebase Chat Application with the help **Google Codelabs** I had basic implemented all the thing need to setup an Firebase but I am getting error about cannot resolving Auth. I am providing snapshot what I had included in external as well as internal gradle.
[image: Project build.gradle file]

[image: Project level build.gradle]

I am following this tutorial
[Google CodeLabs Firebase Chat App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'`
dependency to the app build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a line in your build gradle, try adding this:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

This essentially pulls the missing library from a remote repository to be used in your project.

Read up on how the gradle system works as a part of the Android build system.

Answer (score 0):

With these two dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:x.x.x'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:x.x.x'
```

You also need to add one which is below. This is the part you need to include which is Play Services Auth that's it:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:x.x.x'
```

And move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` below all these dependencies means at last.